# Function doesn't recognize imported package

Tags: python, function, python-import

This is a simple misunderstanding on my part about how the environment works.

I created a function for reading images into a dataframe of histograms, called `files_to_hist_df(files_list)`. It's not the prettiest, but here it is:

```
def files_to_hist_df(files_list):
    '''
    Reads a list of image files and creates a pandas DataFrame of the three-channel histograms.
    '''
    # Instantiate arrays
    blue_array = np.zeros(256)
    green_array = np.zeros(256)
    red_array = np.zeros(256)

    for file in files:
        img = cv2.imread(file, 3)
        # Calculate histograms
        blue = cv2.calcHist(img, channels=[0], mask=None, histSize=[256], ranges=[0,256]).flatten()
        green = cv2.calcHist(img, channels=[1], mask=None, histSize=[256], ranges=[0,256]).flatten()
        red = cv2.calcHist(img, channels=[2], mask=None, histSize=[256], ranges=[0,256]).flatten()
        # Append histograms to arrays
        blue_array = np.vstack([blue_array, blue])
        green_array = np.vstack([green_array, green])
        red_array = np.vstack([red_array, red])

    # Remove instantiating zeros
    blue_array = blue_array[1:]
    green_array = green_array[1:]
    red_array = red_array[1:]

    # Create dataframes
    red_df = pd.DataFrame(red_array).add_prefix('red_')
    blue_df = pd.DataFrame(blue_array).add_prefix('blue_')
    green_df = pd.DataFrame(green_array).add_prefix('green_')
    hist_df = pd.concat([red_df, blue_df, green_df], axis=1)

    return hist_df
```

I stored that in a file called `project_functions.py`.

When I tried to run it in another notebook stored in the same directory, I began with a number of module imports, including `numpy as np`, etc. Among those was `from project_functions import files_to_hist_df`.

When I ran the code in the notebook, I received the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ef8cb473e894> in <module>
----> 1 hist_df = files_to_hist_df(files)
      2 hist_df

~/Melanoma/project_functions.py in files_to_hist_df(files_list)
      5     '''
      6     # Instantiate arrays
----> 7     blue_array = np.zeros(256)
      8     green_array = np.zeros(256)
      9     red_array = np.zeros(256)

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Now, as I said above, I imported Numpy as `np`. Why is that function not recognizing `np` as Numpy from the imported modules?

Comment: You should import `numpy` in `project_functions.py`.

Comment: Imports are not transitive across files. Each file needs to have the relevant ones